# coord_flip() does not work

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I tried to flip the coordinates on my bar plot in `ggplot2` on `python3` but it was not successful. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import ggplot
print(ggplot.__version__)
0.11.5

from ggplot import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# seed
np.random.seed(0)

# toy DF
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.random.choice(range(2001, 2008), 250),
    "w": np.random.uniform(50, 400, 250)
})
# data and axis
plt = ggplot(df, aes(weight='w', x='x'))
# bars
plt = plt + geom_bar() 
# print
print(plt)
```

[image]

```
# vertical bars --> horizontal bars
plt = plt + coord_flip()
print(plt)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this was brought up [long ago](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/239) and does't exist, which is why it doesn't work. Oddly, it doesn't throw an error but just silently doesn't do anything (which is what led me to be confused, google, and find this).